# Smart loading of markers on Google Maps

Tags: performance, svg, google-maps-api-3, png

I have a system where the markers being used are in the form of pngs as these were found to be the fastest performance-wise since I have in excess of 2K markers, and this value can keep growing. However since pngs do not support marker rotation to represent direction, I have to switch these to svgs.

The problem is that svgs in this amount are super slow, and therefore I had attempted a way to switch the pngs into svgs once the zoom level was past a certain value. The issue is that since all the markers convert to svg the program becomes almost non-responsive.

Is there a way to only convert the pngs in the current viewport to svg and these will keep converting/reverting on map panning so that the performance will speed up and so that I will able to rotate the markers in the current view.

```
I created this codepen example to show the performance issue that I am referring to when you simply display the markers and zoom/pan on the map: https://codepen.io/DylanBulteel/pen/bvOMEv
```

I also updated the codepen so that if you select pngs after a certain zoom level they will turn into svgs.

Also a few additional points to clarify:

1) Clustering data won't work as the points will be representing live data that is constantly being updated, and as a result the separate points need to be seen from all zoom levels

2)Markers cannot be hidden at certain zoom levels since the user would want to see where the larger groups of points are from a far out zoom

Comment: What about clustering your markers? It doesn't make much sense to have tons of markers all over the place... you can't even tell where on earth you are... And another idea, instead of updating the markers in the viewport, what about loading **only** the markers that fall within the viewport instead of loading them all? Also you could hide your markers if the zoom level isn't high enough. These 3 options would certainly affect performance.

Comment: Clustering is not an option since the user requires to see all separate points all the time with their individual tooltips, the same for hiding markers at specific zoom levels.
I am attempting to load only the markers that fall within the viewport, however when the viewport is large if there are a large number of svgs this will be an issue. This is why I am looking to use pngs until zoomed in and then convert the pngs in that viewport to svgs to allow marker rotation to represent direction.

Comment: I am honestly not sure your approach to "convert only the PNGs in the current viewport" will make an improvement to performance because you would then need to iterate over all your markers and update the icon each time the user pans / zooms the map. But the answer is, yes, technically you can. 1) Get your map bounds 2) Iterate over your markers and if they fall within the map bounds, do what you need to do. [`LatLngBounds` class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#LatLngBounds) has a `contains` method.

Comment: It's more an improvement in performance as opposed to converting all the pngs to svgs at a certain zoom level, since panning/zooming over svg is way slower than pngs. Ideally we would just use pngs, however there doesn't seem to be a way of rotating pngs, all rotational properties are linked to svgs whereas pngs would require a separate image for each angle which isn't really an option.

Comment: Well... try it and see if it improves. But SVG path is the only way you can rotate a marker icon with the API. Otherwise you could certainly rotate your PNGs using other ways (PHP for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue I did as follows as per suggested by @MrUpsidown:

1) Firstly the bounds of the current viewport were obtained

2) The features drawn on the map are being stored within an object, and I looped through this object and used the latlngbounds method to check whether each feature was within the current viewport boundary

3) If it was the respective feature's map property was set to the map, otherwise it was set to null - rather than deleting and redrawing each feature each time it was found to be more efficient to just make them unavailable for the current map but to retain the object itself in memory.

This went something as follows and improved the panning and zooming drastically when having a very large number of pngs:

```
        var bounds = map.getBounds()

        var result = bounds.contains(Featurecenter)

        if (result) {
            if (feature.map == null || feature.map == undefined) {
                feature.setMap(map)
            }
        }
        else {
            feature.setMap(null)
        }
```

That helped to improve the performance on panning and zooming. Additionally then I implemented the functionality whereas the pngs load initially, however upon passing a set zoom level the pngs would revert to svgs in order to prevent lag on the platform as a result of a large number of pngs being present.

The code for this was as follows (The event is idle as this was combined with the above event for panning and zooming and setting an event for panning directly fires lots of calls upon drag) :

```
           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

            zoom = map.getZoom()

//Zoomcheck is used to prevent the markers from being redrawn if they are already within the correct zoom level

            if (zoom > 16 && zoomCheck == 0) {

                zoomCheck = 1

                svgDraw()
            }
            else if (zoom <= 16 && zoomCheck == 1) {
                zoomCheck = 0

                pngDraw()
            }
            else {
                featureContainer.map((circle) => {
                    //Code to only draw features within current viewport as above goes here
                })
            }

        })
```

If there is a better solution or a further improvement I would be glad to hear about it.